# CSS Transition Height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, height, nav

I've built a responsive nav that is revealed when a button is clicked. This uses a translate to move the shim div to the left. The shim div is also being resized (using JS) accordingly to browser height by setting the min-height property. When the page loads the shim height is animated. I believe it's because I'm using: transition: all, x, x.

I'd like to animate the shim opening without animating the height.

Try refreshing the page a few times to see the height being animated.

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gCoqI

Comment: sounds like you've answered your own question

Comment: ^ Haha, maybe. Do you know of another possible solution?

Comment: Isn't that 'transition' just the image loading/rendering..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just set `min-height` to `100%` on `.shim` in the CSS. That way it doesn't change height and therefore doesn't animate (and requires less JS). Also changing the animation property from `all` to `left` should also work.

Comment: Alex, setting the height and min-height on the div worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `transition: all, ...`, use `transition: left, ...`. This way, you only animate the left property. Changes to other properties are applied instantly.